# Python: convert list of tuples (1 to many relationship) to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a list of tuples into a dictionary-dictionary format, however, i could only get a dictionary-list format. May i know how am i able to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
words = [('food', 'apple'), ('food', 'banana'), ('food', 'pear'),
         ('animal', 'monkey'), ('animal', 'gorilla'), ('animal', 'horse'), 
         ('country', 'UK'), ('country', 'US'), ('country', 'JP')]

dict1 ={}
for k,v in words: 
        if k in dict1:
            dict1[k].append(v)
        else:
            dict1[k]=[v]
        
print (dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'food': ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'], 
'animal': ['monkey', 'gorilla', 'horse'],
 'country': ['UK', 'US', 'JP']}
```

Desired output:

```
{'food': {'apple', 'banana', 'pear'}, 
'animal': {'monkey', 'gorilla', 'horse'}, 
'country': {'UK', 'US', 'JP'}}
```

Comment: What does `dictionary-dictionary` format mean? Your desired output is not nested dictionaries. It's just sets inside a dictionary.

Comment: `{'food': {'apple', 'banana', 'pear'}, 'animal': {'monkey', 'gorilla', 'horse'}, 'country': {'UK', 'US', 'JP'}}` is not a dictionary with dictionaries... those are `set` objects. So **exactly** how you've done above, just use a `set` instead of a `list`. But *why* do you want that?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Note that it's `add` instead of `append` though when using sets.

Comment: hi, thank you for the clarification that it's a set inside a dictionary. i think i understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the dictionary with set values that you are showing as desired output, you can do the following, utilizing `dict.setdefault`:

```
dict1 = {}
for k, v in words: 
    dict1.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)
```